# How do I read this csv syntax into R

Tags: r, csv, import

I am trying to import this csv file directly from the web into R; however, I am getting all the values as column names.

The csv file goes like:

Month/Year, "Index"
"Feb.2019","125"
"Mar.2019","127"
"April.2019","130"

So far I have tried:

```
read.csv("path", header = TRUE) #Not working
read.delim("path", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

In case you want the source URL, you can find it here:

https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/api/PN01288PM/csv

EDIT:
After inspecting the source file and several comments I realized it is sending the information as HTML rather than CSV; therefore, the problem is of a different kind. I will close the question now as I will manipulate the data to read it automatically.

Comment: `read.csv` does work with the data shown in the question but the data in your link is **not** in the same format as the data in the question. Plesae fix your question.

Comment: Fixing the question. I posted the link directly from the documentation and didn't realized it was giving me another format. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source is *not* a plain CSV file, but is formatted with HTML.

```
Mes/A&ntilde;o,"&Iacute;ndice de precios Lima Metropolitana (&iacute;ndice 2009 = 100) - IPC Sin Alimentos"<br>"Feb.2018","123.094735792622"
<br>"Mar.2018","124.074279098189"<br>"Abr.2018","124.106210561863"
<br>"May.2018","124.110950696298"<br>"Jun.2018","124.457010420352"
<br>"Jul.2018","124.821481844788"<br>"Ago.2018","124.952886180169"
```

etc. You'll need to parse this as HTML using another package or perhaps read it as a string and split it up yourself - each row is ended with a `<br>` tag and then within that fields are split by commas.

Comment: This should be a comment. It does not provide an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

No problems here using `data.table`'s `fread()`

```
library( data.table )
data.table::fread('Month/Year, "Index"
"Feb.2019","125"
"Mar.2019","127"
"April.2019","130" ')

#    Month/Year Index
# 1:   Feb.2019   125
# 2:   Mar.2019   127
# 3: April.2019   130
```

Comment: This answer works for the data shown in the question itself so I have reversed the downvote that someone gave to this answer. The problem is with the question, not the answer. It's really the question that should be downvoted, not the answer.  See my comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because the url you provide contains `<br />` in between table rows, you can inspect it opening chrome dev tools.

Try downloading the data from [this link](https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/mensuales/) and loading into R.

Answer (score 0):

I also work with data from this website. I'm not sure how you found that link, but I can tell you that it's wildly easier to just scrape your tables directly. Also, you can use the nomenclature of the link to change the dates over time. (2020-1. 2020-2, ... 2020-12). I do something like this in my scraping code:

```
library(httr)
httr::set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = FALSE)) # bad ssl on the site
r = GET("https://estadisticas.bcrp.gob.pe/estadisticas/series/mensuales/resultados/PN01288PM/html/2018-2/2020-1/")
r = content(r, "text")
r = read_html(r)
r = html_table(fill = TRUE)
r[[2]]
```